# SRAM usage optimization in ARM devices

Tags: optimization, memory, arm, stm32

The relationship between the variable size and the data bus size was confusing for me so I decided to get to the bottom of it by examining the assembly code.
I compiled the source code below in the STM32CubeIDE Version 1.2.0.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE         ((uint8_t)0x20)

uint8_t aTxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int i;  

for(i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++){
        aTxBuffer[i]=0xFF;   /* TxBuffer init */
}
```

Looking at the assembly code confirmed my suspicion. Unless I misunderstood it grossly, this code will allocate an array with total size of BUFFER_SIZE * DATA_BUS_SIZE (Which is 32 bits on Cortex-M) but we will use only the least significant byte of each memory address.

```
for(i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
//reset i to 0
 800051c:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (8000544 <main+0x3c>)         
 800051e:   2200        movs    r2, #0                          
 8000520:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]                        
 8000522:   e009        b.n 8000538 <main+0x30>                 
    {
//store 0xFF in each member of TxBuffer
        aTxBuffer[i]=0xFF;   /* TxBuffer init */
 8000524:   4b07        ldr r3, [pc, #28]   ; (8000544 <main+0x3c>)
 8000526:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
 8000528:   4a07        ldr r2, [pc, #28]   ; (8000548 <main+0x40>)
 800052a:   21ff        movs    r1, #255    ; 0xff
 800052c:   54d1        strb    r1, [r2, r3]
    for(i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
//increment i
 800052e:   4b05        ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; (8000544 <main+0x3c>)
 8000530:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
 8000532:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000534:   4a03        ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; (8000544 <main+0x3c>)
 8000536:   6013        str r3, [r2, #0]
//compare if i is less than 31. then jump to 8000524
 8000538:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (8000544 <main+0x3c>)
 800053a:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
 800053c:   2b1f        cmp r3, #31
 800053e:   d9f1        bls.n   8000524 <main+0x1c>
//pointer to i in SRAM
 8000544:   2000002c    .word   0x2000002c
//pointer to TxBuffer in SRAM 
 8000548:   20000064    .word   0x20000064
```

As the SRAM is at premium in embedded devices I believe there must be some clever ways to optimize usage. One naive solution that I can think of is to allocate the buffer as uint32_t and do bit shifting to access higher bytes but this seems like costly from speed optimization perspective. What is the recommended practice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bus size does not matter in this case. Memory usage will be the the same.

Some Cortex cores do not allow not aligned access. What is unaligned access? Unaligned memory accesses occur when you try to access (as single operation) N bytes of data starting from an address that is not evenly divisible by N (i.e. addr % N != 0). In our case N can be 1, 2 and 4.

your example should be analyzed with optimizations turned on.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE         ((uint8_t)0x20)

uint8_t aTxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void init(uint8_t x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
            aTxBuffer[i]=x;   
    }
}
```

The STM32F0 which does not allow unaligned access will have to store the data byte by byte

```
init:
  ldr r3, .L5
  movs r2, r3
  adds r2, r2, #32
.L2:
  strb r0, [r3]
  adds r3, r3, #1
  cmp r3, r2
  bne .L2
  bx lr
.L5:
  .word aTxBuffer
```

but stm32F4 will faster (in less operations) store the full words 32birs - 4 bytes.

```
init:
        movs    r3, #0
        bfi     r3, r0, #0, #8
        bfi     r3, r0, #8, #8
        ldr     r2, .L3
        bfi     r3, r0, #16, #8
        bfi     r3, r0, #24, #8
        str     r3, [r2]  @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #4]      @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #8]      @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #12]     @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #16]     @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #20]     @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #24]     @ unaligned
        str     r3, [r2, #28]     @ unaligned
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   aTxBuffer
```

the SRAM consumption is exactly the same in both cases

Comment: Yes, I discovered that you can access each memory byte individually at a unique address even for SDRAM regardless of the memory width. As far as I understand this is achieved simply by using something like this for 16 bit wide SDRAM. SDRAM_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS = (MEMORY_ADDRESS - SDRAM_BANK_BASE_ADDRESS) >> 1. First bit of the MEMORY_ADDRESS then determines if we are accessing low or high byte using byte mask feature of the SDRAM during 8 bit LDR/SDR access. But this was far from obvious for me at first.

Answer (score 0):

The given code does not utilize more BUFFER_SIZE*8 bits for aTxBuffer.
Note the following line in your assembly

> 800052c:   54d1        strb    r1, [r2, r3]

Note the b suffix to the instruction here, indicating 'byte'.

In effect, the instruction translates to 'store 1 byte of value 0xFF (stored in r1) at aTxBuffer (stored in r2) + i (stored in r3)'.

So, while the assembly doesn't indicate the end of the buffer, it certainly accesses all bytes in the aTxBuffer array without any waste.

It's possible that your minimal example doesn't capture the problem you face in your actual code but I find it unlikely that the compiler will have such wasted bytes, especially one for an embedded device.

In case you do find that to be the case, you can simply allocate a uint32 array of the same size in bits (or one element higher) and cast the address of the first element to a uint8_t pointer to a uint8_t variable. Now you can access the uint8_t variable as normal. 
Note that such programming should be avoided and is only shown as an example. Specifically, this makes it difficult for compilers to analyze pointer aliasing which makes some optimizations difficult. It also creates some burden on the user; careful memory management will be required to avoid mistakes (for example, you should free only one of these pointers to avoid a double-free error).

Example:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 0x20
// number of elements in int32 will be BUFFSIZE / 4
#define BUFFSIZE_IN_INT_32 (BUFFSIZE >> 2)

// allocate the buffer
uint32_t uint32_array[BUFFSIZE_IN_INT_32];

// point to 1 byte sized elements
uint8_t * aTxBuffer = (uint8_t *)(uint32_array)

// use aTxBuffer as you like
```

Note here that I assume BUFFSIZE to be divisible by 4. If that is not the case, add BUFFSIZE_IN_INT_32 by 1 more.

Comment: So I indeed grossly misunderstood the physical memory address translation! Checking the memory map of the Cortex-M7 for example, each byte is assigned an unique address in the 4GB address space.
What if I use an external memory? For example, if with a 1,048,576 bits x 16-bit x 4-bank SDRAM, would I be able to access each byte at a unique address?

Comment: It depends on the external RAM if its byte-addressable (most are). However, the C compiler should take care of data layout as you expect it to be. According to the C standard, the compiler may NOT insert any padding in between array elements. So arrays of elements of size 1 byte will take exactly 1 byte of space.